# корректное чтение из файла (получить в строку текст файла между A и B)

Tags: c++

Есть мой код; методом исключения выяснил что "плавающая" проблема в приведенном ниже участке (в с++ раньше никогда не писал ничего длиннее пяти строк..):

```
...
using namespace std;
...

void myload (const char *fname) 
{
    bool fnd, work = false;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    string str = "";

    ifstream input(fname);

    while (input.getline(buffer, BUF_SIZE))
    {
        if (strstr(buffer, "sign_begin") && !work)
        {
            work = true;
            fnd = true;
        }

        if (fnd)
        {
            str = str + buffer + "\n";
        }

        if (strstr(buffer, "sign_end") && work)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Предполагается, что в текущем каталоге лежит файл `fname`, содержащий в себе `sign_begin` и `sign_end`.

1. Логика подсказывает, что, возможно, надо как-то файл закрыть? Например, вставляю `input.close()` в конец блока `while` и всё у меня отрабатывает корректно (в цикле, много циклов..). однако вставляю ту же команду сразу за блоком `while`, и код не компилируется.. вряд-ли это правильное решение..
2. Пока задавал вопрос, очень сильно начал подозревать, что проблема в `bool fnd, work = false;` - если по отдельности проинициализировать каждую переменную, то вроде как тоже все работает хорошо. Не знаю откуда у меня такая конструкция в голове.. И как её воспримет компилятор? использую g++
3. Раз на то пошло, возможно есть более "изящное" решение задачи, которую решает приведенный участок кода(?)

Comment: можно весь код в студию

Comment: Весь код занимает 2000+ строк. проблему долго локализовывал, поэтому и привел только проблемный участок кода. Товарищ Harry уже дал исчерпывающий ответ, за что ему спасибо. И Вам спасибо за беспокойство :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Файл закроется сам при выходе из области видимости, при вызове деструктора `input`.
2. Переменная `fnd` у вас **неинициализирована**, т.е. может быть чем угодно. Инициализируйте ее, нет проблем: `bool fnd = false, work = false;`
3. Вы хотите получить строки между строками, в которых есть подстроки `sign_begin` и `sign_end` включительно? исключая эти строки? Опишите поточнее, что именно вы хотите - тогда будет понятнее, что вам ответить на третий пункт...

**Update**

Я бы делал примерно так:

```
bool found = false;

while (input.getline(buffer, BUF_SIZE))
{
    if (!found && strstr(buffer, "sign_begin"))
    {
        found = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        if (strstr(buffer, "sign_end")) break;
        str = str + buffer + "\n";
    }
}
```

Т.е. пока не найдено `sign_begin`, проверяем строки на ее наличие. Нашли - выставили флаг, пошли к следующей строке. Если найден (флаг выставлен) - проверяем на наличие `sign_end`, найдено - выход из цикла (вы ищете одно вхождение?). Не найдено - строка добавляется к `str`. Понятно, что не компилировал, показываю просто схему.

Если надо искать дальше - второе вхождение - то

```
        if (strstr(buffer, "sign_end")) break;
```

меняем на

```
        if (strstr(buffer, "sign_end")) { found = false; continue; }
```

Comment: 3. получить строки между строками, в которых есть подстроки sign_begin и sign_end, исключая эти строки.

Comment: Тогда я бы обошелся одним флагом, а не двумя. Сейчас добавлю код в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, всё отлично заработало!